# Autoencoder with Mixed Data

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, continuous-data, autoencoders, mixed-type-data

Is it reasonable? The categorical features can be binary ("true" or "false") or strings, which are one-hot encoded. Some continuous features may be integers, which are treated as real values. If an autoencoder is an appropriate approach for such mixed data, what would be a reasonable loss function? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Were you ever able to get an answer elsewhere?

Comment: @Greg Not yet... :( I keep a browser tab open on this question hoping any suggestions will come up... :P I have an idea for a "custom" loss function, but I'm not entirely sure if that alone solves the problem of mixed data. I'll probably share it later, but I'm hoping to get some comments first. So stay tuned, I guess... :)

Comment: It depends on your needs, but would using two encoders fit your needs; one for the categorical and one for the continuous?

Comment: But then you wouldn't have a single model that captures all inputs (and their possible interactions) simultaneously, right?

Comment: Yes and no. The reason I mentioned it, is that binary auto-encoders use a different kind of optimization if I remember well (Gibbs sampling?) than continuous. Meaning that one model might not be optional. If you use two models, the interactions end up in a subsequent models that uses the compressed inputs. As stated, it depends on your needs.

Comment: It is possible to create a model with mixed input and mixed, for example, in keras you can define the output layer to be a concatenation of layers, and the losses should be also a list ['mse', 'mse', 'binary_crossentropy']